# How to change access controller redirect/login URL in Yii2?

Tags: php, redirect, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two login systems in my Yii2 application. First is default login system using `User` table, and second uses `sms_account` table. In custom controller I've created action for login, `actionLogin()`. I've added access control for my custom controller, but I'm having problem that when a person is not logged in, it redirects to `site/login`. I want to change redirect to `custom-controller/login` URL in Yii2 access control. My code is:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
        'access' => [
            'class'  => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' =>  [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => false,
                    'roles' => ['@']
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['home'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to change access control URL?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this code.
Note:roles

```
[
    'actions' => ['home'],
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['?']
    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
        return $this->redirect('index.php?r=controller/action');
    }
]
```

Answer (score 11):

You should simply configure your user component :

```
'user' => [
    // ...
    'loginUrl' => ['custom-controller/login'],
],
```

Read more about [`yii\web\User::$loginUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#$loginUrl-detail).

And it should be :

```
[
    'actions' => ['login'],
    'allow' => true,
    'roles' => ['?']
],
```

Read more about [Authorization in Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> This is my updated answer . I thinks it's help you
> ```

```
  public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'access' => [
                    'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                    'only' => ['index','logout','client-create'], // your own action which permission the login
                    'rules' => [
                        [
                            'actions' => ['index','logout','client-create'], // your own action which permission the login
                            'allow' => true,
                            'roles' => ['@'],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                     Yii::$app->response->redirect(['login/login']); 
                     },
                ],            
            ];
        }
```